# wicket: how to stream a resource from a database

Tags: stream, streaming, wicket

I'm trying to generate a sitemap dynamically for a large web site with thousands of pages.

Yes, I have considered generating the sitemap file offline and simply serving it statically, and I might end up doing exactly that. But I think this is a generally useful question:

**How can I stream large data from a DB in Wicket?**

I followed the instructions at the [Wicket SEO page](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/seo-search-engine-optimization.html), and was able to get a dynamic sitemap implementation working using a DataProvider. But it doesn't scale- it runs out of memory when it calls my DataProvider's `iterator()` method with a `count` arg equal to the total number of objects I'm returning, rather than iterating over them in chunks.

I think the solution lies somewhere with `WebResource/ResourceStreamingRequestTarget`. But those classes expect an `IResourceStream`, which ultimately boils down to providing an `InputStream` implementation, which deals in bytes, rather than DB records. I wouldn't know how to implement the `length()` method in such a case, as that would require visiting every record ahead of time to compute the overall length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an `AbsractResourceStreamWriter` subclass:

```
public class SitemapStreamWriter extends AbstractResourceStreamWriter
{
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream output)
    {
        String HEAD = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                      "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\"\n" +
                       "        xmlns:wicket=\"http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd\">\n";
        try
        {
            output.write(HEAD.getBytes());

            // write out a <loc> entry for each of my pages here

            output.write("</urlset>\n".getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the doc of the IResourceStream.length() method:

```
    /**
 * Gets the size of this resource in bytes
 * 
 * TODO 1.5: rename to lengthInBytes() or let it return some sort of size object
 * 
 * @return The size of this resource in the number of bytes, or -1 if unknown
 */
long length();
```

So I think it would be ok if your IResourceStream implementation tells that the length is unknown and you stream the data directly as you get the records from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could return -1, indicating an unknown length, or you could write the result in a memory buffer or disk, before rendering it to the client.

You could also use this file as a cache, so that you don't need to regenerate it every time this resource is requested (remember you have to handle concurrent requests, though). Dedicated caching solutions (e.g. memcache, ehcache, etc.) can also be considered.

It may be cleaner than publishing a static file, although static files are probably better if performance is critical.